# How to resolve "connect Timeout" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var https = require('https');

https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', function (res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);
    res.on('data', function (d) {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
}).on('error', function (e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: Are you able to access it from your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
request.socket.setTimeout(60000); // 60 sec
```

or this

```
request.setTimeout(timeout, [callback]);
```

method to bind socket and create the timeout